# (Qt) Editable QComboBox: don't close popup while entering the text

Tags: c++, qt

The question looks trivial, but I still can't found solution. When the combobox' popup is open, it catches the focus, and I can't enter any text in lineEdit. And if I put the cursor in the lineEdit, the popup expectedly closes. Is there any ways to enter the text and save the popup open at the same time, beside of implementation of my own popup?
Thank you and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you to use QLineEdit + QCompleter. Combobox designed for another behavior (that you don't need).

Comment: QCompleter don't provides me necessary behaviour (I need some complex completion rules). I found some CustomCompleter examples, but it isn't what I need. My idea was to use QComboBox+QSqlQueryModel, then make model select strings which match search conditions each time when text changed. Maybe it isn't better way for this task... Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You still can use QSqlQueryModel with QCompleter ;)